# In Android, NetworkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses() requires API level 9. How can I do this using API level 8?

Tags: android, network-programming

As stated above, how can I get the mobile devices network interface addresses using API 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses()` is available in API8.

Comment: I somehow overlooked this.